# Removing paint from a potentially varnished surface

Tags: paint-removal

Recently while painting I got a fair bit of paint on the skirting and door frames. I included an example of it below. [image]

I was thinking of going at it with some paint thinner but worried it might strip the varinish (or gloss or whatever is on it). Does anyone have a better method?

Also is it possible to spot revarnish or will that look a bad?

Comment: I would try Goo Gone in a non-conspicuous area.

Comment: Next time, damp cloth as you work, or masking tape.

Comment: Scraping the paint off once dry often works - if you are careful. But careful would have used brown paper and masking tape which takes less time…